Story about orbiting brain / super computer
Please help identify this sci-fi story: The course of the story describes how a supercomputer / AI brain is going to be put in orbit, and when it finally is, all of humanity ends up frozen in their tracks as the barrage of info is too much to handle. The author aims to highlight that a most often forgotten yet important function of our brains is in filtering out ‘background noise’ or unnecessary data.

Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy SE! To increase your chances of getting a good answer, please [edit] your question and add more details, such as when you read/watched the work and what works you have already checked and ruled out. For more tips on how to improve your question, take a look at our guide on asking identification questions.
